# Unexpected error in Ansible AWX, can't find solution to fix duplicate entries

Tags: postgresql, docker, ansible, ansible-awx

I have this scenario:

OS: Rhel 7

Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289

docker-compose version 1.29.1, build unknown

Ansible AWX 17.1.0

Command:

```
# docker logs -f awx_task
```

Output

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "elapsed": 0,
    "match_groupdict": {},
    "match_groups": [],
    "path": null,
    "port": 5432,
    "search_regex": null,
    "state": "started"
}
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "db": "awx"
}
Instance already registered awx
Instance Group already registered tower
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(admin) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
[..]
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(admin) already exists.
```

Command:

```
docker logs -f awx_postgres
```

Output:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2021-05-12 10:18:27.238 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.6 (Debian 12.6-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-05-12 10:18:27.240 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-05-12 10:18:27.240 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-05-12 10:18:27.267 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-05-12 10:18:27.292 UTC [25] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-12 10:18:01 UTC
2021-05-12 10:18:27.319 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-05-12 10:18:44.644 UTC [38] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
2021-05-12 10:18:44.644 UTC [38] DETAIL:  Key (username)=(admin) already exists.
2021-05-12 10:18:44.644 UTC [38] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_ac                             tive", "date_joined") VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$150000$CP3hfUVL3id2$b32FSJVzCDL+HlRi//DIn4FRcOsn+knF7uPOyGtE8q0=', NULL, true, 'admin', '', '', 'root@localhost', true, true, '2021-0                             5-12T10:18:44.426469+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "auth_user"."id"
2021-05-12 12:05:42.983 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-05-12 12:05:42.987 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-05-12 12:05:43.043 UTC [50] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-05-12 12:05:43.045 UTC [3002] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-05-12 12:05:43.051 UTC [2267] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-05-12 12:05:43.057 UTC [3011] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-05-12 12:05:43.072 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 31) exited with exit code 1
2021-05-12 12:05:43.073 UTC [26] LOG:  shutting down
2021-05-12 12:05:43.094 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

What happened? Except a DNS registration of server I haven't modify anything during these days.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see the [seemingly similar issue](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/7307#issuecomment-641978692)?

Comment: Yes, it's similar but I can't find any solution, the case is still open